# Popup dialog with round corners

Tags: iphone

I want to create a popup dialog that show in center of a screen. Currently I use a UIView that load manually from a NIB and add as a sub view onto my main view. Is there a better proper way?

I also need to fade out the back ground main view and have round corners on this popup dialog.

Target iOS 6 and later

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

No way to use `UIAlertView` here if you want some super special visuals. However if you're not wanting anything fancy you might give it a try.

By I prefer subclassing `UIView` and doing what I want and how I want with it. It's really cool and it gives you countless possibilities. It may be a bit harder but it's 100% worth it. So personally I'd go for the `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

Create your popup as another view controller and use a segue from the main view controller to load the popup view controller with the type `Present Modally`.

Change the popup view background colour to transparent (clear) and use another smaller sized view with a solid background colour to house your elements in the popup.

To get the rounded corners, add the following code (swift syntax) to the `viewDidLoad()` on the popup view controller.

```
    self.popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.popupView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
    self.popupView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
```